# Displaying part of piecewise function

Tags: functions, piecewise

If I define a piecewise function

```
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{t^2, t < 0}, {Sin[t], t > 0}}]
Which[f[t], t > 0]
```

how do I display only one part of the function? e.g. I want to know what `f` is when `t>0`, how do I get Mathematica to output `Sin[t]`?

(This is a MWE. My actual piecewise function contains thousands of terms when `t<0`, and I only want to study the function at `t>0`.)

**Edit:** Thanks for the responses. I should add that the piecewise function is the solution to a `Convolve` operation. So I'm not sure if the piecewise function is a "Mathematica function" in the strict sense.

Comment: What else could it be if it's not a "Mathematica function in the strict sense"?

Comment: I don't know, I'm a Mathematica newbie. What I mean is, it's a function that isn't expressed as `f[t_] :=`. Instead it's `f = `. Does this make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. Please read a tutorial on [immediate and delayed definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html). Both are functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PiecewiseExpand[f[t], t > 0]
(*    Sin[t]    *)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Simplify` gives the desired result:

```
Simplify[f[t], t > 0]
```

> Sin[t]